# minitest uses example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, minitest

Trying to do a pretty simple integration test with minitest, however it seemingly doesn't set the default_url_option properly so whenever I try to visit a path, it tries to do it on www.example.com instead of my application.

For example:

```
describe "Admin Architects Integration Test" do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  it "should be able to view list of users grouped by architect status" do                                                                                                      
    visit admin_path                                                                                                                                                            
  end                                                                                                                                                                           
end
```

Tries to take me to www.example.com/admin

Comment: The route helper `admin_path` will give you a string like "/admin". How are you seeing `http://www.example.com/admin`?

Comment: How did you configure your app to use Minitest?

Comment: blowmage: It does go to /admin, however trying to get admin_url gives:

ArgumentError Exception: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter

and when I check the current url, it's www.example.com. I'm guessing my minitest setup isn't settings the correct url for my application, so it's defaulting to example.

Also - I'm using the minitest-rails gem with a pretty simple test helper.

Comment: I'd search your app for the string "example.com". It is likely you have this configured somewhere in your app's configuration or your tests. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default_url_options

Comment: Send me an email if you want me to help you troubleshoot this. My email is on my SO profile page.

Comment: Thanks - will do. I've already done a grep of example.com project wide, and the only place it's used is in my factories where I set users emails to userX@example.com.

Comment: Even in a Rails console, when I try to get the x_url from the url helpers, I get this:

ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true